# Crop an image in Python: Image.crop() vs. Image.transform()?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I want to crop an image by selecting a subregion of it to turn into a new image file.

Based on what I see in the PIL docs, I am trying to decide between 2 approaches.

#### For both approaches:

```
    # assume I already have a PIL-opened image called original_image
    # assume I have a crop_box tuple for the area to crop, e.g. (0, 0, 100, 100)
```

### Approaches

1. Cropping the original image directly, and then transforming the returned crop area into a new file. It seems that I'm giving up all the mode data / other metadata about the original image, which would then have to be re-loaded?

   ```
   cropped_image = original_image.crop(crop_box)
   # process cropped version as needed
   ```
2. Do an `image.transform()` in which I select a sub-region

   ```
   # assume I have an output size of (100, 100)
   cropped_image = original_image.transform(size, Image.EXTENT, crop_box)
   # process cropped version as needed
   ```

Is one approach preferable to the other in terms of speed, data preservation, or another important factor that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

The following is from [the PIL.Image documentation](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm) under the `transform` function:

> It is slightly slower than crop

Plus `crop` is simpler and shows your intent. That's what I'd use.